# Executing R script from PHP

Tags: php, r, user-permissions

`index.php`:

```
<?php
    echo exec("Rscript foo.R");
?>
```

`foo.R`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
print("Before!")
#library(rJava);
print("After!");
```

Output on webpage:

```
[1] "After!"
```

Now this is an expected output as `exec` returns the last line from the result of the command.
Now since I want to access the mongodb database which needs `rJava` and `RMongo` libraries I modified the above code a little bit.

`foo.R`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
print("Before!")
library(rJava);
print("After!");
```

Output on webpage:

```
[1] "Before!"
```

Now I don't understand this output. I expected the same output as before i.e `[1] "After!"`. It's as if the R code starting from the library import line doesn't exist at all. I have tested the above code (and the omitted one where I use `kmeans` on the data grabbed from `mongodb`) in `R shell` and it works as expected.

What's wrong with importing a library in a `R` script which is meant to be executed from `PHP`?

---

**Update 1**:
Interestingly, the modified `foo.R` gets invoked and executed as per my expectation if I invoke `index.php` from command line.

```
$ php index.php 
Loading required package: methods
[1] "After!"
```

So my conclusion is that my normal user account can execute `index.php` which in turn can load libraries in `foo.R` but it seems `www-data` user account has no permissions to load libraries in `R`.

So now the question is how do I give permissions to `www-data` to load `R` libraries?

---

**Update 2**:
I solved this issue temporarily by changing apache user from `www-data` to my current user but I'm aware this is a huge security risk and I'm looking for an alternative solution.

Comment: Have you checked exactly what error you are getting in your Apache logs when `www-user` fails to load `R` libraries? In particular, I think you need to find where those R libraries live.

Comment: The other possibility is the library search path is incorrect for the user `www-data`, rather than a permissions issue. Are the libraries installed system-wide or were they installed for your local user?

Comment: @merlin2011 Oh! I think it's the later! Now I remember I have installed libraries in my home directory. I'll now install them system wide and will try with the default apache user. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept if it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should check exactly what error you are getting in your Apache logs when www-user fails to load R libraries. The two most likely culprits are a permissions error and an incorrect library search path.

If the libraries are installed for the local user instead of system-wide, then `www-data` will not be able to find them, but the errors in the Apache logs should reveal this information.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could be that you don't use PHP to directly execute the R script.

You can use a key-value database like `Redis` or a queuing system like `Rabbitmq`. Rather then executing the script directly, send a message to either of these systems.

Execute a php script in command line that polls either of these systems to look for any new messages and when it receives the message it executes the script and responds back with the result from the script.

So it will become a two-way messaging system:

```
Script A ----> Queue ----> Script B  ----> R Script
R Script --result--> Script B ----> Queue ----> Script A
```

This is a bit complicated system to initially implement but definitely secure and scalable.

I would suggest you to look at [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).